# How to access the I/O bits of PCI printer card?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pci, parallel-port

[image]

How can I have a direct access to I/O pins of parallel port of the above PCI card
from user context under Linux?
Output of lspci:

```
lspci -vvvxxxs 03:06.0
03:06.0 Serial controller: TXIC Device 5073 (rev 10) (prog-if 02 [16550])
Subsystem: TXIC Device 3273
Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
NUMA node: 0
Region 0: I/O ports at cf00 [size=8]
Region 1: I/O ports at ce00 [size=8]
Region 2: I/O ports at cd00 [size=8]
Region 3: I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
Kernel driver in use: serial
00: 51 46 73 50 01 00 00 02 10 02 00 07 00 00 00 00
10: 01 cf 00 00 01 ce 00 00 01 cd 00 00 01 cc 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 51 46 73 32
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 00 00
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
80: 51 46 73 50 01 00 00 02 10 02 00 07 00 00 00 00
90: 01 cf 00 00 01 ce 00 00 01 cd 00 00 01 cc 00 00
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 51 46 73 32
b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 00 00
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Is it normal that there is only one record for this I/O card,
but this card occupies two serial and one parallel port ?
Would it be a right plan to access I/O card with PCI Utilities ?
pciutils-3.7.0.tar.gz
from: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/pciutils/pciutils.git
How could I know the meaning of the 256 bytes of my PCI card ?
I think these bytes provide the control/status and data transfer for two serial and one parallel interface.
I note in older time when my parallel card had ISA interface instead of PCI, I could
do it simple with these function:
`ioperm(0x378,2,1), outb(data, 0x378), inb(0x378+1) with #include <sys/io.h>` .

Comment: I have no any /dev/parport*, this card probably isn't supported by Linux now.
But I think it could be enough to use the above PCI Utilities from the user context.
I think the main problem is that there is no any doc about the I/O card side.
In older time this I/O card had ISA interface on the mother board instead of PCI.
And I/O card had doc. about port address and data bits of control and status registers .
So the main difference that I can't see any doc about I/O card since it has PCI interface on the mother board.

Comment: I know the  RaspberryPi is grate for this, but I would like to do it with my desktop pc.
The problem isn't that there is no parallel port on the mother board,
but there isn't ISA interface on the mother board, too and no doc for PCI I/O card.

Comment: Who writes device driver how do you know the interface of the device? E.g.: in case of this I/O card ?